# how to use readlines()

Tags: python, python-3.x, readlines, edgar

**Here on running the following code I am getting an error as below. Can anyone please help me with this.**

```
import urllib
import requests
url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1800/000104746918000856/0001047469-18-000856.txt"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
page.decode('utf-8')
text_list = page.decode('utf-8').readlines()
```

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'

Comment: Why do you think you should use `readlines` here?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you want an list containing each line of what is returned. This code would do the trick:

```py
import urllib
import requests
url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1800/000104746918000856/0001047469-18-000856.txt"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
text_list = page.decode('utf-8').split('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
page.decode()
```

returns a string. readlines() works on file objects. So if you had a file object, you would:

```
linesList = fileObject.readlines()
```

For more details, see [Python readlines description](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_file_readlines.asp)
Answer above shows how to still get lines with your decoded page object using delimiters on the string. File objects are not strings, but work like handles to a file which may have strings in it.